# Reverse Proxying Tomcat Web Applications Behind Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to create a configuration for my virtual host in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Profile, so I modified the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf as follows:

```
# domain: mysite.com
# public: /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
  ServerName  www.mysite.com
  ServerAlias mysite.com
  ProxyPass / http://139.333.222.107:8080/devices
  ProxyPassReverse / http://139.333.222.107:8080/devices

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/mysite.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/mysite.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I run `sudo service apache2 restart` , I got this error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                          [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf:
Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including mod_proxy. Depends on your install (sorry not familiar with Ubuntu) but usually this means the following line will be in your main httpd.conf file:

```
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/modproxy.so
```

Remove the # so it stops being commented out and is loaded and restart Apache.

This link may also help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/341684/how-to-load-the-modules-for-apache2